# Shortest path between vertices of an edge in a graph which should not be the edge itself

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph

I need to find the shortest alternative path of every edge in a weighted undirected graph,i.e , suppose I had an egde (a,b) in a graph ,then I want to calculate the shortest possible path between vetices a and b skipping the direct path,i.e, edge(a,b) . If there is no alternative path then distance should be infinite. I'd to do this for every edge of a graph.I'd tried with dijkstras algorithm (which will break when target vertex is encountered) but it takes too much time to calculate path individually for every edge ,particularly in cases where no alternative path is possible (in that case whole of the graph has to be traversed). Can you propose any other alternative solution to this.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the "not allowed" edge from the graph and then run Dijkstra or any other "normal" path finding algorithm?

Comment: If Dijkstras takes too much time, then I think you are out of luck. Don't think there's a better algorithm known at the moment.

Comment: does your dijkstra implementation use a min heap when finding the next node to be advanced? or do you just iterate through all the verices?

Comment: Apparently it's called the replacement path problem:
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/shortest-paths-disallowing-each-edge

More specifically, it's single-edge replacement path.
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.74.3264%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=L_RVUYaODavy0wGm2ICABw&usg=AFQjCNFIgAa5N6sVs6Io5AgcF3txtzGUkQ&sig2=RIZDQ4tMsngyHw1ky8lnkw&bvm=bv.44442042,d.eWU

Answer (score 1):

I guess what I'd do is adapt Dijkstra's algorithm such that I initially populate the heap/priorityqueue with all the paths of length 2 that don't use that edge (Thanks to titus for catching my earlier mistake). That way, the result that you get will exclude the paths that contain exactly one edge. The result then gets you everything for one particular source, and you can repeat this over all possible sources.

Comment: i think you could end up getting a result as a->c->b, where a->c is actually a->b->c. no? you still need to take care not to use a->b when adding all the paths of length 2

Comment: Ah, true. (I'd actually misread the question initially, but I think we're fine if we just make that check)

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://infoarena.ro/job_detail/575826?action=view-source) is a dijkstra implementation I wrote some time ago, it uses [stl make_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) to find the next node more efficently. The implementation is most likely correct.
**edit:** in the example when reading from file, `n` is number of vertices, `m` is number of edges, `a` and `b` are the edge vertices, the direction is from `a` to `b`, `c` is the weight.
As [Nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760746/nobody) mentioned, you should remove the edge, then add it back, to keep the algorithm as it is.

Answer (score -1):

The solution suggested by `Dennis Meng` is what I would think. But there are some optimization (pre-processing) which could make your implementation faster.

1. segregate the graph in set of connected components (trees) [Hint: use DFS to find connected components].
   -- This way if you do not find the shortest path for the pair (u,v) in the `tree` having node `u` then you can break out of the (inner) loop.
2. Maintain a mapping between each node and the tree that it corresponds to.
   -- this will aid in implementing step-1

Answer (score -2):

You just have to simply remove the targeted edge from the graph before performing dijkstras on it.....